# Xcode 4 workflow when working with multiple dev

Tags: xcode, ios5, storyboard

I tried to find the proper way to work with storyboards when there are many devs on the same project and can't find anything useful.

Before storyboards, we would lock the nib while using it to make sure others would not make modifications at the same time.  This way, merge conflicts with nibs were quite rare.

But now, with storyboards, I can't see having a dev lock the whole thing for an hour before another one can work on its part!  And sure enough, if two of them modify the storyboard, there is a merge conflict. Xcode XML files aren't nice to merge and often enough, the merge causes problem and will in fact corrupt the file so we would prefer to avoid those conflicts.

I wanted to know how other peoples are dealing with this problem?  What workflow does other team use?

Thanks!

Comment: We use multiple storyboards to get around this problem. However, we try and divide them sensibly into particular user journeys so that we are not just using storyboards in the same way as nibs. This is a good question though!

Comment: I'm sure most team are struggling with this issue but there does not seem to be any flawless or official workflow for this.  I'd really like to know how Apple manages this with their internal teams, it sure would help us!

Comment: We have decided not to go with storyboards for now. Mostly because we do an "app-map" of an application in omnigraffle, so the visual part offers us no real value.
Secondly - they offer little real value in a multi-developer context - but have a few drawbacks:
1. Hard to version control (as you mentioned)
2. Don't work on ios previous to 5 (which still is most users)
3. Most apps are not that linear

Comment: We've just started using Storyboards as well and have been running into issues with conflicts and Git, especially if team members are not on exactly the same version of Xcode. I'm not so sure Storyboards are all they're cracked up to be at this point, but hopefully with time our churn will go down on the storyboard file and it won't be such a problem as the project goes on.

Comment: We have this same problem too, hopefully XCode 5's new git features do something to help with this.

Answer (score 5):

The storyboard file format is very different from previous XIB formats, so you might give it a try. If you have real examples of changes that cause merge conflicts which you can't easily resolve, your best bet is to file bugs with Apple at http://bugreporter.apple.com.

In storyboards, items tend to be placed in different areas of the file based on where they're located on the canvas, so once you have a larger storyboard conflicts may become less common.

Answer (score -1):

If I have a merge conflict I just open the file with the "Open As" and "Source Code" and take either the mine>>>> section or the section of the other collaborator.